# Abstract class and object

Tags: c++, object, abstract

I got a first class :

```
namespace Abstract{

    class AbstractClass{
    public:

        virtual void setName(const std::string & _name) =0;
        virtual void print() =0;
        void DynamicCastTest(){};

    };

}
```

And a second :

```
class ConcreteClass : public Abstract::AbstractClass{

std::string type;

public:
    ConcreteClass();
    ConcreteClass(char* a);
    ~ConcreteClass();

    static ConcreteClass* CreateConcreteClass(char* a);

    virtual void setName(const std::string & _name); 
    virtual void print(); 

};
```

But when i want to define my function CreateConcreteClass(char*):

```
static ConcreteClass* CreateConcreteClass(char* a){

    ConcreteClass a;

}
```

Visual cant create the object 'a' because it tells me it's an abstract object.

Why ?

Comment: I can't see what is missing either... Doesn't visual tell you what it think is missing for the class to be complete ? gcc does..

Comment: Do your (de)constructors need to be marked virtual as well?

Comment: I think you probably want your function signature to be `static Abstract::AbstractClass* CreateConcreteClass(char* a)`. Would also recommend using `const` in front of your `char*`s. Finally, you're probably going to want to return a new object from your static factory method; otherwise returning a pointer to a local variable that disappears will cause a crash.

Comment: @PierreBesses You cannot use an abstract class as a parameter type, a function return type, or the type of an explicit conversion, nor can you declare an object of an abstract class. You can, however, declare pointers and references to an abstract class.

Comment: @PierreBesses  Also a class derived from an abstract base class will also be abstract unless you override each pure virtual function in the derived class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried it with VC10. It gives me error C2082 telling me something like redefinition of formal parameter a (I have a german installation so your error message may be different).
Simply rename your variable:

```
ConcreteClass* ConcreteClass::CreateConcreteClass(char* a)
{
    return new ConcreteClass(a); 
}
```

*Edit:* added static for not returning address of a temporary

*2nd edit:* made CreateConcreteClass a static factory function

Comment: I did it, thanks! but now, i have : 1>main.obj : error LNK2019: "public: static class ConcreteClass * __cdecl ConcreteClass::CreateConcreteClass(char *)" (?CreateConcreteClass@ConcreteClass@@SAPAV1@PAD@Z) référencé dans la fonction _main
1>C:\Documents and Settings\i2113ic\Mes documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\test\Debug\test.exe : fatal error LNK1120:

Comment: When i call : Abstract::AbstractClass* newAbstractClass = ConcreteClass::CreateConcreteClass("123");

Comment: isn't there a problem with that: you're returning a pointer to a local variable, so that's going to crash isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, i rewrote my func : static ConcreteClass* CreateConcreteClass(char* a){

 ConcreteClass* result = new ConcreteClass(a);
 return result;
}

Comment: @PierreBesses error LNK2019 is a linker error. You probably have forgotten to implement some of the virtual functions or declared constructors.

Comment: You have defined non-member function `static ConcreteClass * CreateConcreteClass(char *)`, but linker still expects the static member function `static ConcreteClass * ConcreteClass::CreateConcreteClass(char *)` -- it's declared but not defined.

Comment: @MikeTyukanov I think with my 2nd edit I changed this. First I started my answer the only goal was to compile the source. I saw it as an code fragment and for me it was clear it will not link (missing constructor, destructor, virtual method definitions).